# Layout best practices with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, overlay, android-fragmentactivity

I work on a radio/video player (for android tv). I need 3 (fullscreen: all my app is fullscreen) pages (let's call them Main pages) :

- Radio page (audio stream)
- Tv page (video stream)
- Video page (same as tv page but with local server videos)

On this 3 pages I need to show a menu to navigate between the 3 main pages or to close the application. This menu is called by pressing the dpad down key (back to hide).

Each page need a main menu who will come above the main page (to select another webradio or another video). The Tv main page doesn't have any menu page.

For now, I use multiple activities, one for each main page but I have to copy the main menu code...

So I thought about this kind of layout but I'm not sure it's the best way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_container"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_container"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/menu_container"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Question:

1. Is it nice to have only one Activity for the entire application ?
2. If it's OK, how can I do multiple level of menu (for example: my video menu would show first a page with 2 choices and then the filtered list of video). Is it best practice to put a fragment on another fragment ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Answers,

1. It depends on your application design and requirement. But in your case, only one `Activity` you should use.
2. It can be worst practice to put `Fragment` on another. There should be only one `Fragment` at a same time/place on a `Activity` (all other should be cleared out).

Comment: Tx for your answer.
Instead of a fragment in a fragment, should I add one (or more) layout to the main layout to have multiple levels ? Or should I draw my layout programmaticaly ? EDIT: I should clear out the others as you said